# How Do I Get A C++ Code Compiler for Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, compilation

I am learning C++. I have installed Code::Blocks too, but before I can write my program, a message tells me there is no compiler. I have installed everything but it still does not work. I don't need an IDE, but I need a compiler. Is there any C++ command-line compiler that I can use?

Comment: GCC is the most common and free C++ compiler, another one is clang

Comment: The Code::Blocks [FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ) do [list a few](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/FAQ-Compiling_(general)#Q:_What_compiler_can_I_use_with_Code::Blocks.3F).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeblocks can't find my compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309491/codeblocks-cant-find-my-compiler)

Comment: @Angew, yeah, I have. All I get is Visual C++ by Microsoft. I don't use Visual Studio, which I need for that.

Comment: @HamzaInce, my question doesn't focus on CodeBlocks. I just need the compiler.

Comment: Have you tried following an online tutorial on how to install CodeBlocks? Also if you spend some time on stackoverflow, you'll see that this question was probably answered (multiple time) already ^^.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, try to provide more descriptive titles of your questions. People who just see the list of questions and read _Compilers for C++_ can hardly figure out what is that question about. Something like _Missinng a compiler in Code::Blocks_ might be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, please go here http://mingw.org/, click **Downloads** and download either mingw-installer, or GCC compiler collections. Once downloaded, unzip it in some folder.

If you've downloaded mingw-installer - follow installation wizard and install GCC (compiler).

If you've downloaded GCC itself - you can find `gcc.exe` under `bin\` folder. Or you could go to `Computer->Additional Options->Environment Variables` and then edit `PATH` variable, appending semicolon `;` and then path to `bin\` folder. Then restart your command line and you will get `gcc` command from there to compile your `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks  is only the IDE, you need to download the compiler too. I suppose you are using windows, you need to download a version  include the compiler, the name of the installer is like `codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe` . Here `mingw` is the name of the compiler.